# Creating select all checkbox in VueJS trough loop

Tags: loops, vue.js, methods, undefined

I've created some data that are displayed trough a loop as table.
That code seems fine, however in my methods I get an error 'page is not defined'.
Does anyone know how do I define it?

Table:

```
<tr v-for="page in pages" v-bind:key="page">
                <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" v-model="pageIds" @click="select" :value="page.id">
                </td>
                <td>{{page.name}}</td>
                <td>
                  <v-tooltip bottom>
                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                      <span v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"
                        ><v-icon class="icon delete">mdi-delete</v-icon></span
                      >
                    </template>
                    <span>Delete Page</span>
                  </v-tooltip>
                </td>
              </tr>
```

Methods:

```
    <script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    pages: [
      {"id":"/","name":"/"},
      {"id":"/index","name":"/index"},
      {"id":"/about-us","name":"/about-us"}
    ],
    selected: [],
    allSelected: false,
    pageIds: []
  }),

  methods: {
        selectAll: function() {
            this.pageIds = [];

            if (this.allSelected) {
                for (page in this.pages) {
                    this.pageIds.push(this.pages[page].id.toString());
                }
            }
        },
        select: function() {
            this.allSelected = false;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this in your code. it will resolve your error

from

```
v-for="page in pages" v-bind:key="page"
```

to

```
v-for="(page, index) in pages"
v-bind:key="index"
```

Comment: i actually just made a const in if (this.allSelected) {
                for (const page in this.pages) {
                    this.pageIds.push(this.pages[page].id.toString());
                }
            }

Comment: and it worked tho, when I press select all checkbox, all gets unselected. it works opposite way haha

Comment: @DanielRadosa hahaah selectAll button is not there. but i think you are not toggling the this.allSelected properly :D Anyhow, you can also use for(var page in this.pages) may be it's due to vuejs thing. but simple for(page in this.pages) also should work.

Comment: How selectAll button is not there? I tried changing const and stuff, but it keeps doing the same :D